# How can I write this code more elegantly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm writing the same code three times for the different pages of my WordPress site. I feel that it could be written more elegantly but unfortunately I'm not at the skill level yet to achieve this. Is there any way to combine all of this into something more concise? It would also probably help me learn more about what can and can't be done with JavaScript.

```
if (jQuery(document.body).hasClass("home")) {

    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var threshold = 654;
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 654)
        jQuery('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
    else
        jQuery('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
    });

} else if (jQuery(document.body).hasClass("single") || jQuery(document.body).hasClass("page")) {

    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var threshold = 20;
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 20)
        jQuery('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
    else
        jQuery('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
    });

} else {

    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var threshold = 236;
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 236)
        jQuery('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
    else
        jQuery('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
    });
}
```

Comment: I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the right place for your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var threshold = 236;
if (jQuery(document.body).hasClass("home")) {
   threshold = 654;
} else if (jQuery(document.body).hasClass("single") || jQuery(document.body).hasClass("page")) {
   threshold = 20;
}

var scrolled = false;
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {  
    if (!scrolled && jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= threshold){
        jQuery('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
        scrolled = true;
    } else if (scrolled && jQuery(window).scrollTop() < threshold) { 
        jQuery('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
        scrolled = false;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:** I was created a simple demo to show how to implement sidebar scrolls within his parent.
[Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/farnabaz/pen/ntHzo)

Comment: I think it is a good idea to set a local variable to prevent running addClass() "32904290432489324" times.

Comment: @enapupe thanks for you edit, this is more efficient

Comment: as enapupe edited my answer, check answer again he makes it more efficient :) @Desi

Comment: @Farnabaz did you see my last last edit? Actually I was wrong again.. Inverting the order make it check scrolltop() only once! So, it was a good call anyway, because the first version it would check twice. Another approach would be caching scrollTop() inside scroll event.

Comment: @enapupe yes I see, thank for your improvements, I'll change answer and cache `scrollTop()`

Comment: @enapupe I think there is no difference between current code and caching `scrollTop()` because as you say `scrollTop()` run only once

Comment: Yes, there is none, inverting the if order was enough.

Comment: I know this may be out of the scope of the question but would I be able to add another `if` statement to this saying something like..."if the sidebar reaches the end of its container, then remove the `fixed` class and add a `bottom` class?

Comment: @Desi yes you can, read this article http://www.waypointarts.com/blog/2013/06/29/fixing-a-side-bar-while-scrolling-until-bottom

Answer (score 0):

Damn.. I got beat. Well, I'm still posting this anyway.

```
var scrollTopFn = function(amount){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    // this is a ternary statement, basically a shorthand for writing if else statements
    $(window).scrollTop() >= amount 
      ? $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed')
      :  $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
  });
}

if ($(document.body).hasClass('home')) {
  scrollTopFn(654);
} else if ($(document.body).hasClass('single')){
  scrollTopFn(20);
} else {
  scrollTopFn(236);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be simplified to:

```
var $body = jQuery(document.body),
    threshold = $body.hasClass("home") ? 654
                    : $body.hasClass("single") || $body.hasClass("page") ? 20
                        : 236;
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
        jQuery('#sidebar').toggleClass('fixed', state);
});
```

But this one should have better performance:

```
var $body = jQuery(document.body),
    state = false,
    threshold = $body.hasClass("home") ? 654
                    : $body.hasClass("single") || $body.hasClass("page") ? 20
                        : 236;
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if(state != (state = jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= threshold))
        jQuery('#sidebar').toggleClass('fixed', state);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be:

```
var threshold = 236;

switch (jQuery(document.body).attr("class")) {
    case "home":
        threshold = 654
        break;
    case "single":
    case "page":
        threshold = 20
        break;

}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= threshold )
        jQuery('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
    else
        jQuery('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
});
```